# Finding phase shift using complex exponential

Tags: phase

Suppose I have a sine wave $u(t) = \sin(2\pi f t + \phi)$ of known frequency but unknown phase shift and I want to find the phase shift. One way of doing this is multiply-and-adding $u(t)$ by a $\cos(2\pi f t)$ and a $\sin(2\pi f t)$ wave, then using `atan2` to get the phase shift like so:

```
f      = 1;              % 1 Hz.
t      = 0:1/f/100:2/f;  % 2 cycles, 100 samples per cycle.
phi0   = deg2rad(73.42); % Phase shift of the original wave.

u      = sin(2*pi*f*t + phi0);

%% Multiply and Add using Cos and Sin
I      = u * cos(2*pi*f*t)';
Q      = u * sin(2*pi*f*t)';
phi1   = atan2(I, Q);

v      = sin(2*pi*f*t + phi1);
error1 = phi1 - phi0;

fprintf("phi0   = %f\n", rad2deg(phi0));   % phi0   = 73.420000
fprintf("phi1   = %f\n", rad2deg(phi1));   % phi1   = 73.575271
fprintf("error1 = %f\n", rad2deg(error1)); % error1 = 0.155271

figure
hold on
grid on
plot(t, u);
plot(t, v);
hold off
```

Next, instead of multiplying by $\cos$ and $\sin$, I tried multiplying $u(t)$ by $e^{2\pi i f t}$.

```
f      = 1;              % 1 Hz.
t      = 0:1/f/100:2/f;  % 2 cycles, 100 samples per cycle.
phi0   = deg2rad(73.42); % Phase shift of the original wave.

u      = sin(2*pi*f*t + phi0);

%% Multiply and Add using Complex Exponential
Z      = u * exp(2*pi*i*f*t)';
phi2   = angle(Z);       % -pi/2 (-90 deg) out of phase with phi0.

w      = sin(2*pi*f*t + phi2);
error2 = phi2 - phi0;

fprintf("phi0   = %f\n", rad2deg(phi0));   % phi0   = 73.420000
fprintf("phi2   = %f\n", rad2deg(phi2));   % phi2   = -16.424729
fprintf("error2 = %f\n", rad2deg(error2)); % error2 = -89.844729

figure
hold on
grid on
plot(t, u);
plot(t, w);
hold off
```

But the result is 90 degrees out of phase. Why? Does it have something to do with the fact that it's multiplying a real value with a complex value?

Answer (score 1):

Two issues with your assumptions here.  One in the way you are modeling the added phase and the other about he functioning of the `atan2` function.

You are modeling the phase as `u = sin(2*pi*f*t + phi0)` and then making the following comparison:

```
I      = u * cos(2*pi*f*t)';
Q      = u * sin(2*pi*f*t)';
```

This will match the Q (quadrature / imaginary) component with your input signal and, by convention, this will be a 90 degree phase shift as the in phase component is treated as 0 degrees.

Also, according to the MATLAB help page for [`atan2`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/atan2.html):

> P = atan2(Y,X) returns the four-quadrant inverse tangent (tan<sup>-1</sup>) of Y
> and X, which must be real. The atan2 function follows the convention
> that atan2(x,x) returns 0 when x is mathematically zero (either 0 or
> -0).

When this is compared to the `angle` function:

> theta = angle(z) returns the phase angle in the interval [-π,π] for
> each element of a complex array z. The angles in theta are such that z
> = abs(z).*exp(i * theta).

This is roughly equivalent to `angle(z) = atan2(imag(z), real(z))`, I think some of the edge cases may differ.

So the modifications I would suggest are to change `u = sin(2*pi*f*t + phi0)` in both scripts and `phi1 = atan2(I, Q)` to `phi1 = atan2(Q, I)`.

Answer (score 0):

1. Your code only runs if you properly define the variable `i` as the imaginary unit. Standard Matlab convention is either `j` or `1i`
2. You seem to be confusing real and imaginary part. $e^{j\omega} = \cos(\omega) + j\sin(\omega)$ and the phase is defined to be zero of cosine and 90 degree for a sine. It's calculated as the `atan` of imaginary part over real part.

Comment: i or j is defined as the imaginary number in Matlab. You can overwrite this however. Usually, we use ii and jj when looping. That being said, there are many ways to avoid loops in Matlab.